# Bad performance of open source graphics drivers (ATI Mobility Radeon)

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, performance, proprietary

I have a performance problem with my Mobility Radeon HD 54__ graphics card using default open source drivers.
I'm not talking about games but non-Full HD videos. Occasionally video freezes for a short while (sound remains unaffected) and then everything is fine for another while. Sorry for my explanation but I couldn't find words to describe that behaviour.
I cannot install proprietary drivers, because they seem to crash Ubuntu (13.10).

Answer (score 1):

AMD writes pretty crappy drivers for linux. But if you want the official drivers, and can't get them through ubuntu, go to http://support.amd.com/en-us/download , and there you can specify your video card, then they give you a download for the drivers.

Comment: I tried to install AMD's drivers for the second time and it resulted in the same behaviour. :/ Any other ideas?

Comment: have you made sure that the old drivers were deleted? That might help.

Comment: I had a fglrx driver installed, then I tried to install another, but for some reason it didn't delete the old one, and I ended up crashing my whole system.

Comment: then why wouldn't it work in the first place?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: AMD drivers didn't work once, so why could they work if I tried once more?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought maybe the ones on the site might be different, but maybe they aren't